# texting pics, message

Tags: iphone, objective-c

my iphone app has a few programs to text donations, text message and text pics.i would like to integrate these into the App so there is functionality for users to press buttons on the app to automatically text any stuff. Do we have integration in xcode to text specific things?  Does it work with images? please answer asap.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the MFMessageComposeViewController  [Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).  This should meet your needs for composing and sending SMS ('text') messages, but currently it doesn't support MMS (picture messages).

Comment: Unfortunately there is currently no API fr creating MMS.